# can't run kurento-examples-java

Tags: webrtc, kurento

Available example: https://134.209.199.255:8443/

How I run KMS:

```
docker run -d --name kms -p 8888:8888 \
    -v /root/kms/WebRtcEndpoint.conf.ini:/etc/kurento/modules/kurento/WebRtcEndpoint.conf.ini \
    -e GST_DEBUG="Kurento*:5" kurento/kurento-media-server:latest
```

How I run turn server:

```
sudo turnserver -a -o -v -n  --no-dtls --no-tls -u test:test -r "someRealm"
```

How I run run java example:

```
mvn -U clean spring-boot:run -Dkms.url=ws://localhost:8888/kurento
```

1. Content of [/root/kms/WebRtcEndpoint.conf.ini](http://134.209.199.255/WebRtcEndpoint.conf.ini) (not interactive)
2. [KMS docker container logs](http://134.209.199.255/kms.log) (not interactive)
3. [TURN server discovery result](https://ibb.co/Db7YvKB)

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried configuring all the STUN settings (stunServerAddress, stunServerPort and turnUrl)? I can see in the logs: `STUN server Port not found in config; using default value: 3478`. So maybe it's trying to connect to the local stun server on port 3478 which apparently does not exist? I believe there are some free STUN servers you can try to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was no `configuration` property with turn relay information on client side -

for `WebRtcPeerSendonly`:

```
var options = {
          localVideo: video,
          mediaConstraints: constraints,
        configuration: {
            iceServers: [{urls: 'turn:134.209.199.255', username: 'test', credential: 'test'}],
            iceTransportPolicy: 'relay'
        },
          onicecandidate: participant.onIceCandidate.bind(participant)
        }
```

And for `WebRtcPeerRecvonly`

```
var options = {
      remoteVideo: video,
        configuration: {
            iceServers: [{urls: 'turn:134.209.199.255', username: 'test', credential: 'test'}],
            iceTransportPolicy: 'relay'
        },
      onicecandidate: participant.onIceCandidate.bind(participant)
    }
```

After I add it, it start to work.